# Query Optimization, What more can I do?

Tags: mysql, performance, query-optimization

```
Table type: MyISAM
Rows: 120k
Data Length: 30MB
Index Length: 40MB
```

**my.ini, MySQL 5.6.2 Windows**

```
read_rnd_buffer_size = 512K
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 16M
```

Windows Server 2012, 12GB RAM, SSD 400MB/s

## 1 Slow Query:

```
SELECT article_id, title, author, content, pdate, MATCH(author, title, content) 
AGAINST('Search Keyword') AS score FROM articles ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 10;
```

Executing this query takes 352ms uses index. After profiling, it shows that most of the time is spent on Creating sort index. (Complete detail: http://pastebin.com/raw/jT58DCN5)

## 2 Faster Query:

```
SELECT article_id, title, author, content, pdate, MATCH(author, title, content) 
AGAINST('Search Keyword') AS score FROM articles LIMIT 10;
```

Executing this query takes 23ms and does a full table scan, I don't like full table scans.

**The problem / question is, Query #1 is the one that I need to use, since the sorting is very important.**

Is there anything I can do about speeding up that query / re-writting it and achieve the same result (As #1)?

Appreciate any input and help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are simply expecting too much? 350ms for doing a

- `MATCH(author, title, content) AGAINST('Search Keyword')`
- ORDER BY

on 120k records doesn't sound too shabby to me; especially if `content` is 'bigish' ...

Keep in mind that for your "SLOW QUERY" to work, the system has to read **every** row, calculate the score and then in the end sort all scores, figure out the lowest 10 values and then return all relevant row information for it. If you leave out the `ORDER BY` then it simply picks ***the first 10*** rows and only needs to calculate the `score` for those 10 rows.

That said, I think the `EXPLAIN` is a bit misleading in that it seems to blame everything on the SORT while most probably it is the MATCH that takes up most of the time. I'm guessing the `MATCH()` operator is executed in a 'lazy' manner and thus only is run when the data is asked for which in this case is while the sorting is happening.

To figure this out simply add a new column `score` and split up the query into 2 parts.

- `UPDATE articles SET score = MATCH()` etc...  => will take about 300 ms I guess
- `SELECT article_id, title, author, content, pdate, score FROM articles ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 10;` => will take about 50 ms I guess

Off course this is no working solution, but if I'm right it will show you that your problem is not with the SORT but rather with the fulltext searching...

PS: you forgot to mention what the indexes are on the table, might be useful to know too. cf https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-fulltext-index.html

Comment: Well, the content is not big, varchar 255 is the max length for the content field, and that is the largest one. I have indexes on author, title, content all type varchar, and fall fine within the FULL TEXT SEARCH requirements. I am not saying that I am not happy on how things are doing now, but the site is growing and I just want to be sure that I have done what is possible doing with those resources before investing in anything else. I do have some other options that may be more effective options to optimize rather than that query. Any other input that can help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try these variations:

```
AGAINST('word')
AGAINST('+word')
AGAINST('+word' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Try

```
SELECT ... MATCH ...,
    FROM tbl
    WHERE  MATCH ...  -- repeat the test here
    ...
```

The test is to eliminate the rows that do not match at all, thereby greatly diminishing the number of rows to sort.  (Again, depending on `+` and `BOOLEAN`.)

(I *usually* use all three: `+`, `BOOLEAN`, and `WHERE MATCH`.)

`key_buffer_size = 2G` may help also.

You should consider moving to InnoDB, where FT is faster.